# Issues with posting ajax data in php7

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer-11, php-7.1

I have a problem with the POST data on a page, it works under chrome and Firefox but on IE11 exceptionally it does not work. the fact is simple, a form in html poster with an ajax function with jquery1.6 does not work if we do a `var_dump()` php side of global variable `$_POST` send via ajax the variable is null (the version of php is php7.1.18), yet on a php5.3 server (old server it works properly).

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr-FR" lang="fr-FR">
<head>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form_ses10_rech" name="form_ses10_rech" action="index.phpp......." method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nom" value="">
    <input type="text" name="prenom" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="subm" value="Envoyer">
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form_ses10_rech').submit(function(e){
           // e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: jQuery('#form_ses10_rech').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you know the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: remove comment  // e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

your provided code is correct. tested it on Firefox, chrome and IE ( 11.0.75/KB4339093 ) but cant reproduce your problem - the $_POST looks fine to me

can you post your request-header ?

i guess the problem is not in your code

Answer (score 0):

How to post a request-header .. in the controller in application is like

```
public function ajaxController(Request $request){

var_dump($request); //  it is null
var_dump($_POST); // it is null

}
```

have tested until now, i saw a Keepalive configuration in apache. when keep alive is 5 secondes, i work at five seconde, if it  10 seconde it work at ten seconde after refresh page, but go beyong that it's not work .. if 11s .... the request is null and there is no post ... and we are blocked